# Trying to make a button in raylib

Tags: c#, .net, raylib

I'm trying to create a UI button in raylib_cs and I cant seem to find where I'm going wrong, Is anyone able to send me to a tutorial help out with the solution??

```
public bool CanClick()
    {
        Vector2 mousePos = new Vector2(Raylib.GetMousePosition().X, Raylib.GetMousePosition().Y);           // Get the position of the mouse
        if (mousePos.X >= GlobalPosition.X && mousePos.X <= (GlobalPosition.X + ButtonWidth))
        {
            if (mousePos.Y >= GlobalPosition.Y && mousePos.Y <= GlobalPosition.Y + ButtonHeight)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void DetectClick()
    {
        if(Raylib.IsMouseButtonDown(MouseButton.MOUSE_LEFT_BUTTON))
        {
            if(CanClick())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(objectName + " Pos: " + GlobalPosition.ToString());
                if (onClickAction != null)
                {
                    onClickAction();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to explain why it doesn't works and to make the title more clear ?

Comment: I don't see any problems with the code shown here. Have you made sure that you are instantiating your button class with a valid onClickAction. Also make sure you are calling the DetectClick function. These things can be easy to miss sometimes. Otherwise, I don't see any problems.